# Read VMF1 grid file

Tags: python, numpy, grid

What are the efficient ways to read vmf1 grid file (e.g. VMFG_20221231.H00) using python?

Below is first few lines of vmf1 grid file (VMFG_20221231.H00):

```html
! Version:            1.0
! Source:             D. Landskron, TU Vienna (created: 2022-12-30)
! Data_types:         VMF3 (lat lon ah aw zhd zwd)
! Epoch:              2022 12 31 00 00  0.0
! Scale_factor:       1.e+00
! Range/resolution:   -89.5 89.5 0.5 359.5 1 1
! Comment:            vmf.geo.tuwien.ac.at/trop_products/GRID/1x1/VMF3/VMF3_FC/2022/
 89.5    0.5  0.00115662  0.00056181  2.2824  0.0297
 89.5    1.5  0.00115661  0.00056843  2.2824  0.0298
 89.5    2.5  0.00115661  0.00057441  2.2823  0.0298
 89.5    3.5  0.00115660  0.00057922  2.2823  0.0299
 89.5    4.5  0.00115661  0.00058348  2.2823  0.0299
 89.5    5.5  0.00115661  0.00058729  2.2822  0.0299
 89.5    6.5  0.00115661  0.00059052  2.2822  0.0300
 89.5    7.5  0.00115661  0.00059295  2.2822  0.0300
 89.5    8.5  0.00115662  0.00059456  2.2821  0.0300
 89.5    9.5  0.00115662  0.00059563  2.2821  0.0300
 89.5   10.5  0.00115662  0.00059638  2.2821  0.0300
 89.5   11.5  0.00115662  0.00059697  2.2820  0.0300
 89.5   12.5  0.00115662  0.00059671  2.2820  0.0300
 89.5   13.5  0.00115662  0.00059567  2.2820  0.0300
 89.5   14.5  0.00115663  0.00059444  2.2820  0.0300
```

Comment: Open the file. Read one line at a time. Ignore lines beginning with exclamation mark. Split line. Build list after converting tokens to float

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 4 such files, each of 3.3MB in size _(VMF3_20221231.H00, VMF3_20221231.H06, VMF3_20221231.H12,  VMF3_20221231.H18)_.  These 4 files are zenith delay data for 00hr, 06hr, 12hr, and 18hr of the day covering the whole earth with a 2.5deg X 2deg size grid. I want to interpolate zenith delay at my location (latitude, longitude, height) at each 0hr, 6hr, 12hr, and 18hr and take the average.